# How to make an entire row editable when the column editable key is false in MUI DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI's DataGrid to show data. The data of column is coming from an API and I am mapping it to fill the required data

```
 const handleFetch = () => {
    let fetchRes = apiResponse;
    // if (!fetchRes.ok) {
    //   throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    // }
    const data = fetchRes;
    const generatedColumns = data.map((e) => ({
      field: e.field,
      headerName: e.display_name,
      editable: e.editable,
      width: 150,
    }));
```

This is the code for adding a new row

```
 const addRow = () => {
    const emptyRow = {};
    column.forEach((e) => {
      emptyRow[e.field] = "";
    });
    setRow([...row, emptyRow]);
  };
```

I want to add a row in the table and want to make that entire row editable even if the column editable key is false. I tried to make the new row editable by defining it in the row

```
 const addRow = () => {
    const emptyRow = {};
    column.forEach((e) => {
      emptyRow[e.field] = "";
    });
      emptyRow.isNew = true; //to make the row editable
    setRow([...row, emptyRow]);
  };
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?